# RSS and MSE differentiation in scikit-learn tutorial

Tags: scikit-learn

Very simply, what is the motivation for the following apparent discrepancy in [scikit-learn's linear regression example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html)?

```
# The mean square error
  print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
  % np.mean((regr.predict(diabetes_X_test) - diabetes_y_test) ** 2))
```

You can see that the comment refers to the MSE but the example refers to the RSS. My understanding is that the RSS would be found with

```
print("Residual sum of squares: %.2f"
  % ((regr.predict(diabetes_X_test) - diabetes_y_test) ** 2).sum())
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. I assume the author got mixed up with his/her error nomenclature.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/82928)

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen Hey there. I don't understand why I didn't answer the question. It was my understanding the question was: "Why was a mean squared error calculation called residual sum of squares?" My answer to that was that "the author got mixed up with his/her error nomenclature."